# How do I seeds sqlite3 data base in rails activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to populate the flight table through the seed.rb file on sqlit3 db in rails ActiveRecord with the following code:

```
   departure = Date.new(2021, 9, 1)
   arrival = Date.new(2021, 10, 1)

  (departure).upto(arrival).each do |flight_schedule|
   airports.each do |origin|
    airports.each do |destination|
      if origin == destination
        next
      else
        3.times { Flight.create(origin: origin,
                                destination: destination,
                                flight_schedule: flights_time,
                          duration: flights_duration(origin.code, destination.code))}
      end
     end
    end
   end
```

I have a many to many relationships set up between the airport and flight model with references (foreign_key) as follows;

```
class Airport < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :departures, 
             class_name: :Flight, 
             foreign_key: :origin_id, 
             dependent: :destroy

    has_many :arrivals, 
             class_name: :Flight,  
             foreign_key: :destination_id, 
             dependent: :destroy
end

class Flight < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :origin, class_name: :Airport
  belongs_to :destination, class_name: :Airport
  
end
```

Here is the the db schema;

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_07_21_232515) do

  create_table "airports", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "code"
    t.string "location"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "flights", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "origin_id", null: false
    t.integer "destination_id", null: false
    t.integer "duration"
    t.datetime "flight_schedule"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["destination_id"], name: "index_flights_on_destination_id"
    t.index ["origin_id"], name: "index_flights_on_origin_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "flights", "destinations"
  add_foreign_key "flights", "origins"
end
```

When I run rails db:seed
I have these errors:

```
Rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.destinations
```

Rails version 6.1.4
Ruby version 3.0.1p64 (2021-04-05 revision 0fb782ee38) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the schema looks incorrect, `add_foreign_key` should be like this

```rb
add_foreign_key "flights", "airports", column: "destination_id"
add_foreign_key "flights", "airports", column: "origin_id"
```

so i guess your migrations are incorrect, you should check those migrations relative to add `references` and `foreign_key` to `flights` table, it should look like this:

```rb
create_table :flights do |t|
 # ...
 t.belongs_to :origin, null: false
 t.belongs_to :destination, null: false
 # ...
 t.foreign_key :airports, column: :origin_id
 t.foreign_key :airports, column: :destination_id
end
```